# no wifi shows in ubuntu 9.1 & 11

Tags: wireless

I just install Ubuntu 9.1 but i connect my wifi dongle but it not works. I also try in ubuntu 10 & 11 but no wifi network show in my network.
And when I install Ubuntu 12.05 it works properly.
Please solve this problem.
Thank You

Comment: All those releases are beyond end of life. Use a supported version, such as 14.04

Answer (score 1):

You can download kernel image from a higher version of `Ubuntu`. I don't know what `Ubuntu 9.1` is :)
You'll find new kernels at `http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/`.
Choose one that fits your needs, for example this one `http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.2.68-precise/`.
Download these files:

```
wget http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.2.68-precise/linux-headers-3.2.68-030268-generic_3.2.68-030268.201503061936_amd64.deb
wget http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.2.68-precise/linux-headers-3.2.68-030268_3.2.68-030268.201503061936_all.deb
wget http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.2.68-precise/linux-image-3.2.68-030268-generic_3.2.68-030268.201503061936_amd64.deb
```

You probably have an older version of `Ubuntu`, i would suggest upgrading it to a newer one, because I thing it might not work. You have to just do a `sudo dpkg -i *.deb` in the directory, you have downloaded the packages.